# batch script subroutine: Passing arguments

Tags: batch-file, arguments, argument-passing, subroutine

My understanding is that in order to get the date from a file passed into a subroutine as an argument, you must re-set that argument as a variable within the subroutine.  Is this correct?  This doesn't make since to me, so I am wondering if I do not fully understand what is going on.  I can use the passed in argument in practically any other subroutine code except for date extraction.

```
set setupEXE=setup.exe

CALL :SUB_CheckCorrectDate %setupEXE%
GOTO EOF
::----------------------------------

:SUB_CheckCorrectDate
set filename=%1%

:: SUCCESSFUL
for %%x in (%filename%) do set FileDate=%%~tx
@For /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/ " %%A in ('@echo %FileDate%') do @( 
Set file_Month=%%A
Set file_Day=%%B
Set file_Year=%%C
)

:: GET ERROR    
for %%x in (%1%) do set FileDate=%%~tx
@For /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/ " %%A in ('@echo %FileDate%') do @( 
Set file_Month=%%A
Set file_Day=%%B
Set file_Year=%%C
)    

GOTO:EOF

:: ------------------
:EOF
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `%1` to access the parameter, not `%i%`.

The argument variables have the same modifiers as FOR variables, so you can use `%~t1`.

No need to execute a command in your FOR /F. It is simpler to process a string literal using `in ("string")`.

No need for `:EOF` label. Every script has an implicit `:eof`. I like to use `exit /b` instead.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "setupEXE=setup.exe"

call :SUB_CheckCorrectDate "%setupEXE%"
exit /b

::----------------------------------

:SUB_CheckCorrectDate
set "filename=%~1"
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/ " %%A in ("%~t1") do ( 
  set "file_Month=%%A"
  set "file_Day=%%B"
  set "file_Year=%%C"
)
exit /b
```

Comment: You added `setlocal`. Is there no need for `endlocal`, is it maybe implicitly done via the `exit` command?

Comment: @Wolf - Yes, there is always an implicit ENDLOCAL at the end of a script or Called subroutine for any remaining SETLOCAL that were instantiated in that routine and have not yet been ended. This even happens if a routine or script ends because it has reached the end of file, even without an explicit EXIT /B.

Comment: Ah thanks, good to know. On the page [setlocal | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setlocal "setlocal | Microsoft Docs"), they missed to add the `exit` option. Is this a new feature? And, even more important, are the local environments properly stacked on each other?

Comment: @Wolf - Yes, they stack properly, and the behavior has been consistent since the introduction of SETLOCAL. And Microsoft batch/cmd.exe documentation is generally crap - loads of missing information, and sometimes simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you seriously want to write batch scripts, you should take care for the syntax:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "setupEXE=setup.exe"

CALL :SUB_CheckCorrectDate "%setupEXE%"
GOTO EOF
::----------------------------------

:SUB_CheckCorrectDate
set "filename=%~1"

:: SUCCESSFUL
for %%x in ("%filename%") do set "FileDate=%%~tx"
For /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/ " %%A in ("%FileDate%") do ( 
    Set "file_Month=%%A"
    Set "file_Day=%%B"
    Set "file_Year=%%C"
)

:: GET ERROR    
for %%x in ("%~1") do set "FileDate=%%~tx"
For /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/ " %%A in ("%FileDate%") do ( 
    Set "file_Month=%%A"
    Set "file_Day=%%B"
    Set "file_Year=%%C"
)    

GOTO:EOF

:: ------------------
:
```

Comment: ...and maybe also take care to the right way of returning from sub routines via `exit /b`

Comment: @Endoro _**"if you seriously want to write batch scripts, you should ..."**_ use `Rem` instead of palliatives like `::` etc. Downvote due to this bad mentoring preambule.