# WinSCP batch script to download multiple files from multiple IPv6 hosts

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

Someone please help to create a script file to simply execute from my Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

I have a list of of host with IPv6 address as `[X25:F0:B2:F314::02]`, `[X25:F1:B2:F914::56]` so on, like 25 hosts. And from each host I need to download 300 files `revenue.xml`, `prodcut_growth.xml`, `loss.xml`..... so on like this. While downloading for each file I want to append date and time so file will be saved as `revenue_07_09_2017.xml`.

I tried by following procedure but failed:

```
cd "c:\Program Files\WinSCP"
winscp.com /command "open user:password@[X25:F0:B2:F314::02]" get "/home/user/revenue.xml" "C:\downloaded\revenue.xml.%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%"
get "/home/user/loss.xml" "C:\downloaded\loss.xml.%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%""exit"
#Second host starts here
winscp.com /command "open user:password@[X25:F1:B2:F914::56]" get "/home/user/revenue.xml" "C:\downloaded\revenue.xml.%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%"
get "/home/user/loss.xml" "C:\downloaded\loss.xml.%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%""exit"
exit
```

I tried to execute above batch file but not helped.
Please suggest some approach. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use /command but /script mode generating the script on the fly like described in https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_file_list#scripting replacing put with get (and the order of arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [batch file with a sub routines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19006067/850848):

```
@echo off

call :download [X25:F0:B2:F314::02]
call :download [X25:F1:B2:F914::56]
call :download ...

exit /b

:download
echo open ftp://username:password@%1/ > script.tmp

call :addfile revenue.xml
call :addfile loss.xml
call :addfile ...

echo exit >> script.tmp
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=script.tmp
del script.tmp
exit /b

:addfile
echo get "/home/user/%1" "C:\downloaded\%1.%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%%" >> script.tmp
exit /b
```

*(though you will also want to modify the target path with the host, as otherwise the files will overwrite one another)*

---

Another option is to use [Parametrized WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers).

Comment: I have added an easier way to add more files